# solution for Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error as

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

in console of browser

```html
<button type="button" class="post-review" onclick="postReview(360_MAH_GE)">Post</button>
```

```js
<script>(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {postReview(360_MAH_GE)
};}}}})</script>
```

Comment: put quotes around '360_MAH_GE', unless, its supposed to be an object, thats a different story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `360_MAH_GE`. Try a simple `var 360_MAH_GE;` in the console to see the same error.

1) If it's supposed to be a variable, you can't use numbers in your variable names.

2) If it's supposed to be some value, you can make it into a string by surrounding it in quotations like `'360_MAH_GE'` or `"360_MAH_GE"`.